# Create lists from text file in python

Tags: python, list, parsing

I have a text file with the following content:

```
Matematics
Name1 Surname1
Name2 Surname2
Name3 Surname3
History
Name1 Surname1
Name2 Surname2
Name4 Surname4
Name5 Surname5
```

I would like to ask if it would be possible to append all the `names surnames` for each subject in a separate list.

I can discriminate `name surname` from `subject` string with: `if string.count(' ') > 0:` or `if string.count(' ') == 0:`; and an in intermediate passage could be to add the same symbol (for example `>`) to the beginning of each `subject`.

But I'm confused on how to generate a loop that creates a different list of `names surnames` for each subject.

Comment: Could you post the relevant information from the link into your post as well?  Also include the code that you've already written to address the problem you have.

Comment: Please don't paste links for files to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to 宏杰李's answer, perhaps you could store all the category lists in a dict like so:

```
{
    Mathematics: ['Name1 Surname1','Name2 Surname2', 'Name3 Surname3'],
    History: ['Name4 Surname4','Name5 Surname5', 'Name6 Surname6'],
}
```

using:

```
import csv
exampleDict = {}
currentCategory = ''
with open('file.txt', newline='') as f:
    for row in reader:
        #if the row is a category (mathematics/history)
        if ' ' not in row:
            currentCategory = row
            exampleDict[currentCategory] = []
        #if the row is a 'Name Surname'
        else:
            exampleDict[currentCategory].append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open('file.txt', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) == 2:
            print(row)
```

out:

```
['Name1', 'Surname1']
['Name2', 'Surname2']
['Name3', 'Surname3']
['Name1', 'Surname1']
['Name2', 'Surname2']
['Name4', 'Surname4']
['Name5', 'Surname5']
```

or list comprehension:

```
lists = [row for row in reader if len(row)==2]
```

out:

```
[['Name1', 'Surname1'],
 ['Name2', 'Surname2'],
 ['Name3', 'Surname3'],
 ['Name1', 'Surname1'],
 ['Name2', 'Surname2'],
 ['Name4', 'Surname4'],
 ['Name5', 'Surname5']]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that

Comment: @Giovanni Spirito please accept my answer if the code works